How can i quickly start a AlphaGo project?
I want to slove a problem using MCTS, such as AlphaGO. How can i quickly start using rllib? I didn't see that in the tutorials.
I have run DQNs algorithm, but i don't find AlphaGO in the RLlib tutorials. Is there such a AlphaGO example?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
